# HALO support on recent compilers for C++ coroutines

Tags: c++, optimization, coroutine

I have read the article [Using Coroutine TS with zero dynamic allocations](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1365r0.pdf), and the author insists that HALO would work for coroutines and he provides an [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/g/26viuZ) which shows generator example HALO applied with clang 5.0.

However, with more recent version of clang(clang 13.0.1 on godbolt) I can see calls to operator new. As a matter of fact, I cannot find any recent compiler which supports HALO for corouine. I have tested on MSVC 2019/2022, GCC 11.2 and all assembly shows calls to operator new.

Is it true I can rely on HALO as the author insisted in that article? For instance, RVO was pretty reliable even before C++17 which brings copy ellision into standard. What should I care to expect HALO for my coroutines?

Comment: For the record, GCC 12.2 still does not implement HALO, so I would not rely on it unless you wish to tie yourself to clang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original example does HALO with -O3, just not with -O2.

Seems like HALO does happen, but depends on additional optimization passes.

All I did was update it to C++20 and stdx -> std.

https://godbolt.org/z/qrvWo68Yz

Comment: Interesting! I also noticed that HALO didn't trigger for me, but didn't realize this is a matter of `-O2` vs `-O3`. I filed an issue with the clang: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56262 - let's see if this was an intentional change or an accidental regression

Comment: Turns out this was only a temporary regression in clang. It is fixed in clang-trunk, i.e. should be fixed with the new clang-15 release